# Serialize and DeSerialized derived classes from the base class

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, .net-2.0

I am trying to create a base class where I can inherit from it (to add properties to the derived classes) and the utilized the Load and Save methods from the base class. I find myself writing the Load and Save over and over and I'd like to apply some DRY to it...

```
namespace Common

{
  using System;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Xml.Serialization;

  public abstract class ApplicationSettings
  {
    protected ApplicationSettings()
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationSettings Load(string fileName)
    {
      if (!File.Exists(fileName))
      {
        return null;
      }

      XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationSettings));

      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
      {
        ApplicationSettings param = (ApplicationSettings)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
        return param;
      }
    }

    public void Save(string fileName)
    {
      XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationSettings));
      using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
      {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
        writer.Close();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Given this abstract class, I then want to derive a class such as:

```
namespace Common
{
  using System;

  public class ApplicationParameters : ApplicationSettings
  {
    public ApplicationParameters()
    {
    }
    public string AuthorizationCode
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
    public string ReferenceNumber
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
  }
}
```

For the Derived class, I should be able to  do something like

> ApplicationParameters parameters =
>   ApplicationParmeters.Load("settings.xml");

However, in the implementation above, an compiler error occurs when I attempt to cast the ApplicationSettings to the ApplicationParameters class when I call the Load method in the base class.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the top level class generic so that the Save/Load methods can support multiple types:

```
public abstract class ApplicationSettings<T>
{
    public static T Load(string xml){ // Implementation }

    public static void Save (T obj) { // Implementation }
}

public class ApplicationParameters : ApplicationSettings<ApplicationParameters>
{
}
```

Or you could just make the static methods themselves generic:

```
public abstract class ApplicationSettings
{
    public static T Load<T>(string xml){ // implementation }

    public static void Save<T>(T obj){ // implementation }
}
```

You will now notice that the Save/Load methods from the abstract parent class are strongly typed to the child so that the following line will work as expected:

```
ApplicationParameters parameters = ApplicationParameters.Load("settings.xml");
```

or

```
ApplicationParameters parameters =
    ApplicationSettings.Load<ApplicationParameters>("settings.xml");
```

Depending on which method you use.

Comment: Using the generic at the class level was exactly what I was trying to do... I also used the GetType() suggestion from another answer but the system will not let me mark both as answers...

Comment: Also, using the generic at the class level, I moved the "load" into the derived class constructor and then had the constructor call the base Load method... (Thanks, Dave)

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing typeof(ApplicationSettings) with GetType().

Using this mechanism you will also tell the serializer that ApplicationParameters is a child class of ApplicationSettings. You do this via [XmlInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.type.aspx)

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(ApplicationParameters))]
class ApplicationSettings
```

The latter is a requirements of the serializer because otherwise it won't know what class to instantiate.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using XmlSerializer ?

Unless you must control the way the output XML looks, [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) is recommended

See [here](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/), for example

Comment: This is an interesting way to go, but puts a requirement of .Net 3.0 as the minimum. I should have stated that, unfortunately, I still have to maintain and write some .Net 2.0 application...

Answer (score 0):

How about a constructor in your `ApplicationParameters` class that takes an `ApplicationSettings` as an argument and copy the shared properties from one to another? And then just set the not shared properties to be null or the default...